# How to get Optional value using @Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have a customer repository class with some query

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customers, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customers> {
   @Query("select c from Customers c where c.id = ?1 and c.deleted = false")
   Optional<Customers> findCustomerById(Long id);
}
```

Entity Class:

```
import com.ntric.hariom.inventory.enums.CustomerStatus;
import com.ntric.hariom.inventory.enums.CustomerType;
import com.ntric.hariom.shared.domain.AbstractEntity;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customers extends AbstractEntity {

private String name;

private String mobile;

private Long accountId;

private String address;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private CustomerType type;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private CustomerStatus status;

private boolean isDeleted;

private String panNumber;

private String vatNumber;

}
```

While running the application i am getting following message.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: deleted of: com.ntric.hariom.inventory.domain.Customers
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1873)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)

The stack trace so very large so i am pasting only the error part.

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: i recently edited the question

Comment: @Deadpool why would he do that? This is (hopefully) supposed to be JPQL, not SQL. And there's really no reason to use SQL for such a query.

Comment: Since it is a JPA query, is there necessary to mark this query as native?

Comment: @MilanPaudyal post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception, and post the code of the Customers entity (which should really be named Customer). Also post the complete code of the repository, including imports.

Comment: @JBNizet when i was using customerRepository.findById(id). It was working fine. But i also have to check the status so i created query in repository which is not working now.

Comment: That's not at all what I asked. Post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception, and post the code of the Customers entity (which should really be named Customer). Also post the complete code of the repository, including imports.

Comment: Now the error seems related to 'deleted' property in entity class @MilanPaudyal

Comment: Rename the field `isDeleted` to `deleted`.

Comment: Thank you it's working, but  jpql query suggestion is shown for deleted when i try to use isDeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   deleted

This is because the property is called `isDeleted`. Rename it to `deleted` and this part of the problem will be resolved. Besides, it will make possible to name the getter `isDeleted`, which is more appropriate for a boolean.

Now to the second part of the problem, which is more like an advice on improvement. You don't need a native query, the following query method should do the job.

```
Optional<Customer> findByIdAndDeletedFalse(Long id);
```

Note that the entity was renamed which makes it less confusing.